# How to configure JBoss server in IntelliJ with server base dir and a settings.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, configuration, jboss7.x

I'm trying to switch from Eclipse to IntelliJ Ultimate. But I have trouble configuring an application server.

**What I have:**

- IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2020.3
- a JavaEE application running on JBoss EAP 7.1

**What I already achieved:**

- Adding an application server in Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Application Servers: I added a JBoss Server and specified the JBoss home directory
- Adding a Run/Debug Configuration where I chose the JBoss server, added the artifacts which should be deployed, added some VM options, specified the JRE

**Where I am stuck:**
Here are the things I miss from the Eclipse configuration, and I can't find any documentation or help about that:

- In Eclipse, there is a "server runtime environment" which specifies a "server base directory" and a "configuration file" (settings.xml) in addition to the server home directory and JRE. Where can I find these settings in IntelliJ?
- Alternatively, there is the "launch configuration" in Eclipse, where you can define "program arguments" in addition to VM arguments. These also seem to set the server config and base dir.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please check "Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Application Servers". As for "launch configuration" - you could configure options in run configuration.

Answer (score 0):

There are instructions from IntelliJ site:

[Application Servers](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/application-servers-settings.html)

[Application server run configurations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-run-debug-configuration-for-application-server.html)

Update:
Basically you add your JBoss server

Settings->Application Servers- click + icon to add server

[image: screenshot here]

Then in run configurations you add and config  your JBoss server
[image: screenshot here]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32188744)

Comment: The 2 links provided do, in fact, _not_ answer the question.  I've looked over them closely and as a 20+ year user of Eclipse and various server connectors, there does not appear to be any equivalent functionality as asked by the OP from what I've seen.  I'll keep looking and adjust this answer as appropriate.

Comment: IntelliJ Ultimate does provide server run configurations for JBoss EAP. The links provided show you how to do this. I have added  more details. Note: the free community edition I believe does not provide JBoss EAP support. Also Ultimate comes with free support so take advantage of that